# NodeJs Selenium - GetAttribute() return empty while there is a value

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my HTM, I have the following :

```html
<input _ngcontent-cws-c18="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-toggle="tooltip" numberonly="" id="PLUNumberNumber_PLUNumber" name="PLUNumber" title="8956" min="undefined" max="999999">
```

I'm using Selenium with NodeJS :

> "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-beta.4"

When I run :

```js
let pluElem = await driver.findElement(By.id("PLUNumberNumber_PLUNumber"))


let number = {
        autocomplete: await pluElem.getAttribute("autocomplete"),
        class: await pluElem.getAttribute("class"),
        datatoggle: await pluElem.getAttribute("data-toggle"),
        id: await pluElem.getAttribute("id"),
        name: await pluElem.getAttribute("name"),
        title: await pluElem.getAttribute("title"),
        min: await pluElem.getAttribute("min"),
        max: await pluElem.getAttribute("max")

    }

console.log(number)
```

All attributes but the title attribute get returned :
[image]

Any idea why this specific title attribute is never returned ?

**That's systematic with the title attribute.**

**Any idea why this specific title value isnt recognized ?**

**Or any idea of a workaround ?**

thank you!

---

FYI

`elem.getProperty('attributes')` shows up the same issue :

[image]
*name atrribute has a value*

[image]
*title attribute has no value*

Comment: What locator did you use ?

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL.

Comment: @pmadhu no, sorry. It's customer prod.
@cruisepandey ```By.css()``` but I dont think the problem comes from here as the other attributes are well returned

Comment: Would need to see the code, but have you handled the promise correctly? Are you using `async/await`

Comment: @demouser123 i think I have handled Promises correctly. Yes using async/await. I dont think these are related. Again, ```elem.getAttribute("name")``` works fine  but ```elem.getAttribute("title")``` returns an empty string.